# How to override material design in WPF MVVM for a single control and use default style of WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, material-design

I am developing a WPF MVVM application.

I have used [material design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_Design) for text box, button and tab design.  I am using a data grid inside the tab control.

I would like:

- to override material design style for data grid.
- to use default WPF style only for data grid.
- Scroll bar is not visible and want to make it visible.

How can we achieve that?

Comment: If you are using Material Design, you your self implemented it in a default style, or you are using someone else style. You will need to find the original style and explicitly apply it

Comment: I am using material design,hence default style is material style.I want use default style visual studio provide only to data grid. @TheGeneral

Comment: OP and up-voter perhaps should take a refresher of [ask].  Good luck!

Comment: @MickyD please advice me what change I need to make in question

Comment: @sagartech Yes exactly, However it doesn't change the fact you will need to get a copy of the (default) standard vanilla style and explicitly apply it to override the default material design style you have applied globally

Comment: Consider updating your question to include any research you have done; any links to articles; and also code attempts you have tried. [mcve].  Otherwise it makes the question kinda broad or read as a set of _requirements_ and will result in speculative answers.  This will help us help you. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

This is not an ideal way, but it works:

```xml
<DataGrid
    [...]
    RowBackground="White"
    CellStyle="{x:Null}"
    ColumnHeaderStyle="{x:Null}"
    RowStyle="{x:Null}"
    RowHeaderStyle="{x:Null}"
    Style="{x:Null}" 
    [...]>
</DataGrid>
```

Output:

[image]

[MaterialDesign Styles for `DataGrid` Control](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/ControlStyleList#datagrid)

Comment: It worked fine.But scroll bar is not visible though I can scroll down.I have set both horizontal and vertical scrollbar visibility to true. still scroll bar is not visible

Comment: @sagartech: How is this related to your original question? Please edit your question and include your current XAML markup.

Comment: @AmRo Any way to disable scroll style since scroll bar is not visible for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case override style for a type not working in window ,but when I tried in App.xml it works. In my case the control is toggle button. you can change the style for data grid. the code is :

```
  <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/IG/IG.MSControls.Core.Implicit.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/IG/IG.MSControls.Toolkit.Implicit.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.Blue.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Indigo.xaml" />

            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                            <Border CornerRadius="8" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"                  
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF0F0F4B" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF73ADDE" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF150404" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>




        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```